# Looping through an object to display the grades of a student object and the function displays undefined, what could be the reason?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, foreach

I am doing an online course and practising what I am learning.
I just wanted to create a function, that takes an object and loops through an array element of the object using forEach.

So I don't want to change anything. The reason why I am doing it just to practice forEach method combined with an object.

When I use this following function, it displays this:

15
18
14
17
undefined

Normally it shouldn't display undefined at the end. I wonder, what I did wrong with the coding.
Can you help me please?

```
    let student = {
    firstName: "Sam", //string
    lastName: "Doe", // string
    hasGraduated: false, // boolean
    age: 21, // number
    grades: [15, 18, 14, 17], // array of numbers
    interests: ["computers", "books"] // array of strings
};

function showContent(obj){
  obj.grades.forEach(function(grade){
    console.log(grade);
  })
}
console.log(showContent(student));
```

Comment: The `undefined` is not because of the `console.log()` inside of `showContent` function but because of `console.log(showContent(student));` since it it finishes without returning any value.

Comment: I strongly recommend that whenever you use `console.log()` that you put some UNIQUE prefix in front of what you are outputting so that you know WHICH console.log() output that information:  `console.log("showContent returns:", showContent(student));` and `console.log("grade is:", grade);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the last line `console.log(showContent(student));`

because the function `showContent` does not have any return value, so the last line console will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just drop the last line `console.log(showContent(student));`
Or instead of logging the grades in the fn you can return them.

```
obj.grades.forEach(function(grade){
    return grade;
  })
```